# Changing the format of the output in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `A`. I am identifying locations on each row of `A` which has element `1`. However, I want to change the format of the output. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])

C=[]
for i in range(0,len(A)): 
    B=np.where(A[i]==1)
    C.append(B)
print(C)
```

The current output is

```
[(array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),), (array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int64),), (array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),), (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),)]
```

The expected output is

```
[(array([[1, 2, 3],[0, 2, 3],[0, 1, 3],[0, 1, 2]])]
```

Comment: Do you always have the same number of 1s in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])

C=[]
for i in range(0,len(A)): 
    B=np.where(A[i]==1)
    C.append(B[0].tolist())
C = [np.array(C)]
print(C)
```

Output:

```py
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 2]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have the same number of `1s` in the array, you can just combine [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and a [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

```
C = np.where(A==1)[1].reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
```

*NB. if you don't have the same number of `1s`, then you can't build a non-object array.*

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```